# Unity Wheel Collider Unstable Torque

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

The problem is this: when the car's skid angle reaches large values ​​(150 - 180 degrees), the torque is no longer supplied to the wheels. This is a feature of the unity wheel collider.

So, is there any way to fix this? I need the car to be able to spin 360 degrees (donuts), and also to be able to stay in a skid for a long time.

I transmit the torque in the standard way: **wheelCol.motorTorque = engineTorque * verticalInput;**

Here are my wheel colliders settings:

[image: Here are my wheel colliders settings:]

I tried to make a fake rotation by adding relative torque and forward force, but it's not quite right...

Comment: I'd recommend you to play with Asymptote and Extremum Slip and Value parameters, starting from the default values and changing them one by one. You clold event write a script that will simulate the same input every time and record the track of the car to comare them later and better understand what those parameters are for. For 100% I can say that your problem lies in that area.

Comment: I have already tried hundreds of different combinations of wheel collider settings and the result is the same...

Comment: How the result can be the same if you've used different parameters? Maybe the problem is not in the WheelCollider then?

Comment: I mean that with small values ​​of the settings of the colliders, the car turns 180 degrees and the wheels are blocked, and with large values, the car stops skidding...

Comment: I didn't get it still. From your explanations its hard to figure out what is the effect you're getting and what is desired effect, and also not enough info on how you're applying torque. Could you provide a script and a short video with different settings and effects?